# How check length of related list inside Entity with EF Core and Include?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have next structure Class with related List (Many - One):

```
 public class ContractorPpeItemHonestSign
    {
        [Key] 
        public int Id { get; set; }
       ...
        [InverseProperty("ContractorPpeItemHonestSign")]
        public virtual List<IssueHistoryHonestSign> IssueHistoryHonestSigns { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I trying do filter all Classes where List.count == 0 like this:

```
  public class SignsWithFilterAndPaginationSpec : BaseSpecification<ContractorPpeItemHonestSign>
    {
        public SignsWithFilterAndPaginationSpec(SignsSpecParams signParams)
            : base(x => x.ContractorId == signParams.ContractorId
                && x.DeletedDate == null
                && x.IssueHistoryHonestSigns.Count == 0)
        {
            AddInclude(x => x.IssueHistoryHonestSigns);
            ApplyPaging(signParams.PageSize * (signParams.PageIndex - 1), signParams.PageSize);
        }
    }
}

  public class SpcificationEvaluator<TEntity> where TEntity: class
    {
        public static IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery(IQueryable<TEntity> inputQuery, ISpecification<TEntity> spec)
        {
            var query = inputQuery;

            if (spec.Criteria != null)
            {
                query.Where(spec.Criteria);
            }

            if (spec.OrderBy != null)
            {
                query = query.OrderBy(spec.OrderBy);
            }

            if (spec.OrderByDesc != null)
            {
                query = query.OrderByDescending(spec.OrderByDesc);
            }

            if (spec.IsPaginataionEnabled)
            {
                query = query.Skip(spec.Skip).Take(spec.Take);
            }

            query = spec.Includes.Aggregate(query, (currentEntity, include) => currentEntity.Include(include));

            return query;
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work ;((( **Why and how** can i achieve this goal?
Also i can to filter a result in memory, because all includes are done.. But it isn't my case.

Also i think that WHERE clause doesn't work too ...

Comment: I see that filer will not work, because you need `query = query.Where(spec.Criteria)`. What else do not work?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv lol :D You're right!) I'm too careless :D Thx for help!

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I trying do filter all Classes where List.count == 0

I think you meant the following:

> **Requirement**: Given an `IQueryable<ContractorPpeItemHonestSign>`, give me all `ContractorPpeItemHonestSign` that has no `IssueHistoryHonestSigns` at all.

How about this:

```
IQueryable<ContractorPpeItemHonestSign> inputItems = ...
var inputItemsWithoutHonestSigns = inputItems
    .Where(inputItem => !inputItem.IssueHistoryHonestSigns.Any());
```

In words: from the sequence of ContractorPpeItemHonestSigns in object inputItems, keep only those ContractorPpeItemHonestSign that have no IssueHistoryHonestSigns at all.

Entity framework will do a GroupJoin of tables ContractorPpeItemHonestSign and IssueHistoryHonestSigns, and keep only those ContractorPpeItemHonestSign that have no IssueHistoryHonestSigns at all.

If you want to do the GroupJoin yourself, join on the foreign key `IssueHistoryHonestSign.ContractorPpeItemHonestSignId`:

```
IQueryable<ContractorPpeItemHonestSign> contractors = ...
IQueryable<IssueHistoryHonestSigns > issues = ...


var contractorsWithoutIssues = contractors.GroupJoin(issues,

    contractor => contractor.Id,                  // from every contractor take the primary key
    issue => issue.ContractorPpeItemHonestSignId, // from every issue take the foreign key to contractor

    // parameter resultSelector, from every contractor with its zero or more issues
    // make one new:
    (contractor, issuesOfThisContractor) => new
    {
        // select all Contractor properties that you plan to use
        Id = contractor.Id,
        ...

        HasIssues = issuesOfThisContractor.Any(),
    })
    Where(contractor => !contractor.HasIssues);
```

A third method:

```
IQueryable<ContractorPpeItemHonestSign> contractors = ...
IQueryable<IssueHistoryHonestSigns > issues = ...

var contractorsWithoutIssues = contractors
    .Where(contractor => !issues.Where(issue => issue.ContractorPpeItemHonestSignId == contractor.Id)
    .Any());
```

In words: from all contractors, keep only those contractors where there isn't any issues that has a foreign key that refers to the primary key of the contractor.